# Has anyone ever had to exceed 1000 concurrent executions in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm currently using ~500 concurrent executions and this tends to reach up to **5000** easily, is this a long term problem or is it relatively easy to make a quota increase request to AWS?

Comment: 500 concurrent executions would mean you need to add an queue management / workflow management system to make it scale able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting quota increases is not difficult, but it’s also not instantaneous. In some cases the support person will ask for more information on why you need the increase (often to be sure you aren’t going too far afoul of best practices), which can slow things down. Different support levels have different response times too. So if you are concerned about it you should get ahead of it and get the increase before you think you’ll need it.

Answer (score 0):

To request an increase:

- In the AWS management console, select **Service Quotes**
- Click **AWS Lambda**
- Select **Concurrent executions**
- Click **Request quota increase**